# Resizing after animation in autolayout

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have constraint using Visual Formatting that looks like this...

```
V:|-75-[basic][photo(220)][tiles(75)]-0-[detail]-[remark(>=25)]-[spacer(25)]-[agent(>=150)]-50-[map]-15-[share]-15-[disclaimer]-(>=50)-|
```

The detail view has an event handler that when the view is click it expands from 50px to 800px. The event is working but the autolayout doesn't seem to handle the resizing. I have tried...

```
.needsUpdateConstraints() 
.updateConstraints()
.layoutIfNeeded()
```

On all of the views including children and superviews.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried this `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: @khuong291, yeah i did. Sadly it hasn't done anything

Comment: Are you getting any error in console like missing/voilation of autolayout constraint.

Comment: @ArunGupta I am but they are only envolved with google maps. So I am not 100% sure if that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: I think i got your issue. Try to add NSLayoutConstraint like below.                   NSArray *cHeightZero = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[messageView(0)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [self addConstraints:cHeightZero];
    NSArray *cActualHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[messageView(60)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];                                                                          Check this link: https://github.com/quantumarun/BottomUp-Animation/blob/master/Animations/Category/UIView%2BBottomAnimation.m